# How to get limit on integration for a convolution of two density functions

Tags: integration, convolution, density-function

For two density functions:
Suppose again that $Z = X + Y$.

Find $f_Z(z)$ if

$$f_X(x) = f_Y(x) = \begin{cases}
x/2, & \text{if $0\lt x\lt 2$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I understand this is a convolution $f_X \star f_Y$ but I don't understand how to obtain the limits of integration since they are not $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

$X = x \\
Y = Z - x$

$f_Z(x) = \int {f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx}$

$0 \lt x \lt 2 \\
0 \lt z-x \lt 2$

so:

$x \leq z \\
z-2 \leq x$

and now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower bounds on $X$ are both $0$ and $Z-2$, so $X\gt\max\{0,Z-2\}$.

Upper bounds on $X$ are both $2$ and $Z$, so $X\lt\min\{2,Z\}$.

So the integral is

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{x=\max\{0,z-2\}}^{\min\{2,z\}} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\;dx.$$

Or, to split into two cases:

For $0\lt z\lt 2$,

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{x=0}^{z} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\;dx.$$

For $2\leq z\lt 4$,

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{x=z-2}^{2} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\;dx.$$